# Why are widgets added to a horizontal layout ordered right to left in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, user-interface, layout, qt-designer

I've just discovered something I find weird - here is a video of a desktop capture of QtDesigner 5.6.2:

- https://gofile.io/?c=JscfYH

I add a horizontal layout, add the first button in it, it ends up centered. Then when I add the second button, the second button is somehow on the left side, while the first button is at right?!

[image: qtdesigner]

As far as I remember, when I add stuff to layouts in say Python Qt code, the thing ends up being ordered left-to-right - and here, it looks like the ordering is right to left?!

I've found this [quote](https://books.google.com/books?id=hvBZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=qtdesigner+order+in+horizontal+layout+right-to-left&source=bl&ots=rPcU_8bZXT&sig=ACfU3U23kqxfB-FJySiwovFIzOfO9NTn_g&hl=da&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjt9PGR-tXmAhVWhlwKHQDpCmgQ6AEwAnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=qtdesigner%20order%20in%20horizontal%20layout%20right-to-left&f=false):

> A horizontal layout widget lays out widgets in a horizontal row, from left to right (or right to left, for right-to-left languages)

The central widget also has `layoutDirection` set to `LeftToRight`.

How can I "persuade" QtDesigner to draw the widgets in a QHBoxLayout in left to right order?

---

EDIT: After setting the second button's horizontal `sizePolicy` to fixed (so there is more space in the layout), it turns out that - after I tried dragging it to the right of the first button several times, eventually the two buttons ended up switching places - so I have them in the expected right to left order now!

However, there are no changes in the Object Inspector hierarchy (the first button is still the first child of the layout), nor I can notice any other relevant property of the buttons change. So, I am still at loss - what is the behavior of QtDesigner in respect to horizontal layout ordering supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an artefact of how the Designer interface is set up.

By default, the Widget Box is on the left. So when you drag a button to the layout, it will usually enter the layout from that side. If you drag the button very slowly, you will see that once the button is fully over the layout it will light up, and a blue indicator line will appear on its left edge. So now wherever you drop the button inside the layout, it will be added on the left. Normally, this all happens so quickly that you don't notice it.

To add it to the right, you would need to drag the button all the way to over until the blue line appears on the right. Or do an end run around the layout, and start by entering it from the right.

PS:

The Object Inspector sorts by object-name, so the order won't necessarily reflect what is seen in the layout.